# Good reasons to separate REST API from authentication server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, server

This is a very basic and maybe quite general question, but I think it is appropriate to at least ask it here. I have a React front-end and following a tutorial I have also created a node.js backend for authenticating users.

I now want to add a REST API -would I ideally integrate it in the same node server that I already wrote, or are there good reasons to separate my REST API and my Authentication into two different node.js applications?

Comment: There is no need to separate them if you only will have one application/service, beyond scalability or other infrastructure issues.

Comment: This is a decision that comes with the use case, and decisions of this type comes with 2 things. Constrains and Quality attributes, so if you find quality attributes like scalability, modificability, performance, etc... and the constrains to do so are not high, then may be it makes sense, otherwise just keep it simple and in the future expand the solution in the direction you expect...

Comment: I hate it when I'm saying this but the answer is that what you ask depends on project's needs. There must be a reason to do that separation, considering for example the scalability. If there is no reason try to keep it in a simple way and put them together.